# C# не могу получить поле через рефлексию

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть класс:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private static readonly string ProtocolName = "prtclname";
}
```

Мне нужно получить его поле `ProtocolName` из вне через рефлексию. Пробовал так:

```
var field = typeof(ExampleClass)
    .GetType()
    .GetField("ProtocolName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Почему-то возвращает `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var field = typeof(ExampleClass)
    //.GetType() - у System.Type тоже есть Type
    .GetField("ProtocolName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Comment: блин, так тупанул, спасибо!

Comment: @KuzCode а галочку?

Comment: @aepot вчера ещё не мог поставить

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]